# Getting error on a script

Tags: mysql, lua, garrys-mod

I created a script for the game Garry's Mod, but once is loaded on some servers, it gets the next error:

> [ERROR] addons/ulib-master/lua/ulib/shared/hook.lua:110: addons/applysystem/lua/applysystem/init.lua:13: bad argument #1 to 'pairs' (table expected, got nil)
>       fn - [C]:-1
>           unknown - addons/ulib-master/lua/ulib/shared/hook.lua:110

How can i fix it? this is the line 13:

```
for _, row in pairs(results[1].data) do
```

If needed, theres the entire function where the error is created:

```
db:Query("SELECT * FROM "..ApplySystem.MySQL.TableName.." WHERE delivered=0 AND status='Accepted.'", function(results)

        for _, row in pairs(results[1].data) do

            local steamid64 = row.steamid
            if steamid64 != "" or steamid64 != nil then

                local TransfSteamID = util.SteamIDFrom64(steamid64)
                RunConsoleCommand("ulx","adduserid",TransfSteamID,ApplySystem.MySQL.DefaultRank)
                db:Query("UPDATE "..ApplySystem.MySQL.TableName.." SET delivered=1 WHERE steamid='"..row.steamid.."'  ")
            end
        end

end)
```

Comment: It seems to me results[1] is nil instead of a table. My best guess is you're query didn't return any results

Comment: `results[1].data` that is. If `results[1]` was `nil` then that would be an error about attempting to index `nil`.

Comment: Correct. commenting using a mobile phone isn't that handy. ;) I meant results[1].data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed, thanks guys, it was because i were trying to retrieve nil values.